# Unexpected behaviour from absolute positioned descendant of relative parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following html code:

```
<body>
    <ul class='navbar'>
        <li class='navItem'>
            <div class='dropBox'>
                <div class='dropTitle'>
                    Careers
                </div>
                <div class='dropContent'>
                    <!-- further menu items -->
                    <!-- HR Roles , IT Roles -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- more menu items -->
            <!-- Home -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And am trying to achieve a visual that looks like this:
[image]

To reach this result, I have set the `<ul>` with class `navbar` to be `position: relative` and have set the descendant element `<div>` with class `dropContent` to be `position: absolute`. The `<div>` with class `dropBox` can be toggled between visible and hidden. The result this gives is:

Before opening menu:
[image]

After opening menu:
[image]

After reading up online, I thought a `position: absolute` element (in my case the `dropContent` class) would be placed in the document flow *below* the closest `position: relative` ancestor (in my case the `navbar` class). Instead, the element is being placed *on top* of the closest `position: relative` ancestor.

To try to get around this, I tried setting the `margin-top` of my `dropContent` class to be `100%`. It turns out this has pushed the `dropContent` class to the bottom of the viewport - so the 100% is being taken relative to the viewport and not the `position: relative` parent.

I have read many posts online discussing the behaviour of relative and absolutely positioned elements and have removed extra CSS from my code to try and isolate the issue, yet still can't seem to get the result I am after.

Can someone please advise where the gap is in my understanding of `position: relative` and `position: absolute` ? How could I achieve the result I am looking for ?

I am looking for a HTML and CSS solution - not a solution using Javascript.

Comment: Please post your HTML+CSS as an SO snippet (the button is in the toolbar)

Comment: You should make `.navItem` or `.dropBox` relative - and then specify `left: 0; top: 100%` for `.dropContent`

Answer (score 0):

Margin will always push the content inside its parent.Try below code

```css
.navbar{
  background:#E4E4E4;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
.dropBox{
  position:relative;
}
.dropContent{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  background:grey;
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class='navbar'>
        <li class='navItem'>
            <div class='dropBox'>
                <div class='dropTitle'>
                    Careers
                </div>
                <div class='dropContent'>
                    <div>HR Roles</div>
                    <div>IT Roles</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- more menu items -->
            <!-- Home -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?